Azure AD Authentication to ASP.NET Core Web API
I'm setting up ASP.NET Core Web API to use Azure AD authentication and it's throwing the following error. The overall setup of process is that the client application obtains a token from Azure AD, which it then uses to authenticate requests to our backend .NET Core Web API.
Error: response status is 500

System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<g__Handle|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Step 1: I have registered both the client and Web API in Azure:

Step 2: I updated appsettings.json file for the API registration:

Step 3: in the Startup class, I have added the authentication code in the ConfigureServices method:

Step 4: I also added UseAuthentication call in the Program.cs:

I don't have a whole lot of experience in this area (authentication & authorization), so any guidance on how to move forward would be greatly appreciated.
Since I haven't passed the token from the client application, I was expecting a 401 code, but I'm encountering a 500 error instead.

If possible please share your code repo by masking your credentials in appettings.json file.

Refer this SOThread which address the same issue.You need to configure the JWTOptions..AddJwtBearer(options =>{})

@Landon Please check if the solution below helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

The Error your facing is because configuration of Program.cs .

Error: response status is 500 System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no
DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using
either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or
AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).

To Avoid the error, follow below steps:

Change the Program.cs file code as shown below.

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
namespace YourNamespace
{
   public class Program
   {
       public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
       }
       public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
           Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
               {
                   webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
               });
   }
}


Configure AzureAd in Startup.cs class as shown below.

startup.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
namespace apiswaggerad
{
   public class Startup
   {
       public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
       {
           Configuration = configuration;
       }
       public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
       {
           services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
              .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration, "AzureAd");
           services.AddControllers();
           services.AddSwaggerGen();
       }
       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
       {
           if (env.IsDevelopment())
           {
               app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
               app.UseSwagger();
               app.UseSwaggerUI();
               
           }
           else
           {
               app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
               app.UseHsts();
           }
           app.UseHttpsRedirection();
           app.UseStaticFiles();
           app.UseRouting();
           app.UseAuthorization();
           app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
           {
               endpoints.MapControllers();
           });
       }
   }
}


Starting from .NET 6, the Startup.cs class is combined with Program.cs, so there's no need to create a separate Startup.cs class. You can configure everything directly in the Program.cs file.

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration, "AzureAd");
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

Output:


@Landon Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
